# Simplest way to validate non-library module

Tags: xquery

What is the simplest way to validate there are no syntax errors in an XQuery file? I want to test a number of xquery files as a part of routine testing to verify that no bad files exist with simple syntax errors. Generally for library modules I import the library module and that is enough to validate syntax of the file.

Answer (score 0):

BaseX has an option [`RUNQUERY`](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Options#RUNQUERY) that can be used to disable query execution, so it only gets parsed. For using the command line, [use the `-R off` flag](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Command-Line_Options#BaseX_Standalone).

The query can be passed as string, here I'm using the very simple query `1+1`, which is totally valid and will not return any output, but a return value of 0.

```
basex -R off "1+1"
```

Passing an invalid query will return a syntax error message, and a non-zero return code.

```
basex -R off "1foo"
Stopped at [snip], 1/2:
[XPST0003] Expecting separator after number.
```

I guess there will be similar options for other XQuery implementations, but they're not standardized, so you'll have to look them up in the individual manuals.